# Angular - Is a script allowed inside a ng-view?

Tags: angularjs

Maybe a trivial question here (new to Angular) - however can't seem to find any definitive answer.

Am trying a simple script within it and it doesn't seem to work, is a `<script>` within the ng-view html allowed?

So in my index.html i have the usual:

```
<ng-view></ng-view>
```

And in my ng-view (set by `/when`) - the page shows "Here is my ng-view content" so i know the ng-view works. Just the script isn't working.

```
<script>
    alert('its working')
</script>

Here is my ng-view content
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share your code here.

Comment: create a plunk/jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No** `<script>` tags are not read in the view because that's the way `jqLite` in angular works. If you want scripts in templates to be evaluated, include `jQuery` before `AngularJS`. If `jQuery` is included, the script will be evaluated. Try removing `jQuery`, and you see the originally observed behavior.

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CKKcAM)
You will see that if you comment the jQuery script the alert won't work.

[Angular jQlite Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

You can also include the custom `JavaScript` files in the index page.